# Styled Component Pseudo element not receiving props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am passing this text prop to this component but the pseudo element doesn't receive the props. I have tested it and it works fine outside of the pseudo element. How would I also pass the props to the pseudo element?

```
export const OR = styled.span<{ text: string }>`
          align-self: center;
          background-color: #cbd9e2;
          border-radius: 50%;
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 2.5rem;
          font-weight: 500;
          color: white;
          :before {
            content: ${({ text }) => text};
            text-transform: uppercase;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            font-size: 1.875rem;
          }
        `;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add a `&` sign before such elements with styled components. So:

```js
export const OR = styled.span<{ text: string }>`
          align-self: center;
          background-color: #cbd9e2;
          border-radius: 50%;
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 2.5rem;
          font-weight: 500;
          color: white;
          &:before {
            content: ${({ text }) => text};
            text-transform: uppercase;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            font-size: 1.875rem;
          }
        `;
```

EDIT: based on [this github issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/388), pseudo elements that use content must be written as such:

```js
// without props
&::before {
    content: "blah";
}


// with props (please note the quotes that surround the prop
&::before {
    content: "${p => 'blah'}";
}
```

So in your case, the right syntax might be:

```js
&::before {
            content: "${({ text }) => text}";
            text-transform: uppercase;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            font-size: 1.875rem;
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer DoneDeal0. Upon testing this, I found out that the `&:` is not necessary. But the correct syntax is indeed `content: '${({ text }) => text}';`. The QUOTES are necessary.